# Redefine label in Django modelform

Tags: django

I have a Django model in which I have a `models.CharField` named `level`

I then create a ModelForm from this model, and I want the level to be a `select` from a ChoiceField.

So I create a new widget in the ModelForm.

The only problem is that then it seems like I can't redefine the labels for the `level`. It only appear as "level" in my form.

```
from django import forms
from events.models import Event


class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("RT","RT"), ("RT+","RT+"), ("RI", "RI"), ("RI+", "RI+"), ("RS", "RS"), ("RS+", "RS+"), ("RE", "RE")]) 

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        labels = {
            "title": "Titre de l'évènement",
            "level": "Niveau de la randonnée", # HERE: wont rename the label
            "map_url": "Lien Google Map de l'itinéraire",
            "date": "Date et heure de l'activité (au format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM)"
        }

    

        exclude = ("slug",)
```

Answer (score 2):

`labels` attribute works only for fields generated automatically. Quote from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

> Fields defined declaratively are left as-is, therefore any customizations made to Meta attributes such as widgets, labels, help_texts, or error_messages are ignored; these only apply to fields that are generated automatically.

You can specify label for explicitly defined fields with [`label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#label) argument:

```
level = forms.ChoiceField(label='Some label', choices=[("RT","RT"), ("RT+","RT+"), ("RI", "RI"), ("RI+", "RI+"), ("RS", "RS"), ("RS+", "RS+"), ("RE", "RE")])
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thank you very much.